# jasper reports - need to find the quartile

Tags: jasper-reports

Lets say I have a table with 3 columns. I need to find the quartile of the first column and print it in 3rd column. All these columns are in detail band.

The problem is that, my quartile works correct only for the last row. Other rows have incorrect values because at the time of evaluation, not all the values of the 1st column are available. I tried all the evaluation options in textfield but to no avail.

Please suggest me a way to get all the values of the 1st column to calculate the quartile and write it to the 3rd column.

Answer (score 0):

Tried long and hard in jasper but couldnt, so calculated the quadrants in DB and assigned the quartile by comparing with the each quadrant.